# Why do I get Source Kit Service terminated error?

Tags: swift, ios8

With second line something wrong, what?

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("xxx", withExtension: "momd");
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.init(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
```

[image]

Comment: You are working with beta software, that's a bug.

Comment: the semicolon's seem to make crashing worse for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is the `";"` letter end of the first line, I removed it, and now it works, no popup anymore, that was an interesting side effect

Comment: Could you please include the complete working code?

Comment: I only removed the ; letter from end

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had imported missing files in bridged header.
After I deleted it the error notification gone.

Comment: @VincentSaluzzo It's fixed in Xcode 6 GM.

Comment: Just encountered the same issue on XCode 6.0.1 again and this one solved my problem as well *thumbsup*

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I created about 6+ swift files for one or two targets and SourceKit Service Failure errors occurred. I found I was importing Frameworks that I was not using. So I deleted many of the import lines across the .swift files. For me, it was helpful; I am getting (much) less error.

Hope this helps.

KW

Answer (score 0):

I run across this every once in a while too. As near as I can tell, it's an issue that occurs when you try to do something that the type checker doesn't think is valid - I run across it *a lot* when writing for-in loops. You should [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com), detailing what code, exactly, produces the error.

For now, you'll probably have to play with it until you find a combination that doesn't make the realtime-compiler angry.

Comment: I crash the SourceKit about every two minutes. I don't know *the thing* that's causing it, because it seems *everything* causes it. One sure-fire way is to update a line of code from one type to another - so for instance if you had a line of code appending an array of Items and you change the base type to be an array of Things, boom. But that's only one of many, many crashes I've see and most of them I can't determine.

Comment: @Maury That's interesting, for me it seems to have gotten much stabler. I'm only crashing it maybe three times a day now.

Comment: That's the even weirder part. Today it's crashing all the time, in some cases only seconds apart. Yesterday I got maybe five crashes total, doing the same sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

Set the target to 7.1 fix my issue. Hope this helps you.

Update:
I have a working solution here, works for me:

[Error Xcode 6 --> Error SourceKit terminated. Editor functionality temporarily limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063055/error-xcode-6-error-sourcekit-terminated-editor-functionality-temporarily-l/26477858#26477858)

Hope can help