# XCode 6 Beta 6 SourceKitService Terminated

Tags: xcode6

Since beta 6 I instantly get this message when I open my Project?
Afaik this is due to some lines of code making problems for the swift compiler?

Did anybody figure out what I have to look for that causes this error in beta 6?

Thanks!

Comment: I have experienced it since Beta 1. Every time I included some Swift code in my project, that message will popup and I lose syntax coloring. It restarts itself, then quit again. Guess that's the price to pay for beta software

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has helped me twice now is deleting subdirectories under the Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ directory.  I found this tip elsewhere, maybe on this site or elsewhere on the Net.  My SourceKitService was terminating so often I couldn't even code.  After deleting those file, it was pretty stable again.

Comment: didn't help in my case - SourceKitService keeps crashing all the time, literally at least in beta 6 - older betas are still very stable in my case (no crashs at all)

Answer (score 0):

It's not about your code, it's about XCode itself. Since it is only in Beta, everybody has got these problems and I have to agree this is quite annoying... I even saw it in youtube tutorials so don't be afraid.
Let's just hope it will be fixed in the final version !

Comment: yeah sure, but I read in some other questions that it the crash is caused by code which is not wrong code but triggers the bug in xcode - e.g. one thread named long string concatenations causing the sourcekitservice to terminate.... - I never had this problem in previous version. Still when I use beta 5 everything is fine..

Answer (score 0):

Will you check the XXX-bridging-header.h if any none existing header file imported.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173389/527539

Answer (score 0):

updating to the GM solved the problem for me...